# Application instance is not getting initialized with Robolectric and powermock

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, powermockito

I have an activity which uses application instance for app level book keepings. I am saving app instance in static member after its creation(in application subclass itself). It works fine if I run with only Robolectric, but if I use Powermockito with Robolectric the application is not getting created and member varialble is null when I try to access it from activity.

Comment: Show us your test code

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your application class to the `PowerMockIgnore` annotation list.

E.g.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*","your_application"})
```

Hope it helps.